# Vim(ruby):NoMethodError: undefined method `specifications'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

I'm using Vim 7.3 on Windows 7. When I try to open a .rb File i get this error.
    Vim(ruby):NoMethodError: undefined method `specifications' for "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1":String
 The file opens after I press Enter, but with no syntax highlighting. I have the following vim plugins: rails.vim surround.vim nerd_tree.vim nerdcommenter.vim snipmates.vim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if the problem is with one of the vim plugins. I just installed all the plugins you mentioned in win7 and I have no such problem. However I had a similar error reproduced when I had rubygems 1.8.5, and I tried to run a rake task. Here is a link to a forum that talks about that same rubygems error [link](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=575&aid=29232&group_id=126)

To find out your version, run

```
gem -v
```

The solution for us was to downgrade rubygems

```
gem update --system 1.7.2
```

EDIT:

@Tyler-long is telling me, that Ruby Gems fixed the problem, and an upgrade also fixes the bug. Then you can just do:

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: I met the similar problem today. Instead of downgrade, I updated it to the newest version and problem resolved: gem update --system

Answer (score 3):

tpope has fixed this. It will be in the next release of vim. Meanwhile, you can upgrade your ruby-vim ftplugin.

Replace $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/ruby.vim with the latest version from https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/ftplugin/ruby.vim

Comment: This solution is an actual fix for the problem.  Thanks!