# Error opening ruby file in gvim

Tags: ruby, vim

When I open Ruby files in gvim I get following error:

```
Error detected while processing C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\ftplugin\ruby.vim:
NoMethodError: undefined method `specifications' for "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1":String

E121: Undefined variable: s:ruby_path
E51: Invalid expression: s:ruby_path
```

There isn't any ruby.vim I can find under C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\ftplugin\ either. Does anyone know about this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a broken install.  Try reinstalling vim.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179808/vimrubynomethoderror-undefined-method-specifications/6254751#6254751

Sounds like the same question..

Answer (score 3):

You can add **s:ruby_path** in $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/ruby.vim, for example:

```
let s:ruby_path="d:/ruby/bin"
```

So, it would be right!

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I had that flashing error running for about a year and never cared to fix it. I am currently tinkering with vim, I decided to fix that, and your solution got rid of it.